# What is a cone in $\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: definition

What is a cone in $\mathbb R^n$ ? By logical, I would give the definition :

$$\exists !p\in C: \forall x\in C, [x,p]\subset C,$$
or equivalently
$$\exists !p\in C: \forall x\in C, \forall t\in [0,1], p+tx\in C.$$

Could such a definition work ? Is there an other definition ?

Answer (score 1):

A set $K\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is a cone if for each $x\in K 
\text{ and }\alpha\in~\mathbb{R}_{++}$ we have $\alpha x\in K$. That is, $K$ is a cone if $\alpha K\subset K$ for each $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}_{++}$.

I would translate this definition to a more logical vocabulary as:

$$\forall \alpha\in\mathbb{R}_{++} (x\in K \implies \alpha x\in K).$$

Comment: I don't know what is $\mathbb R _
{++}$.

Comment: @user330587 $\Bbb R_{++}$ usually denote $(0,\infty)=\{x\in\Bbb R\mid x>0\}$

Comment: This is the same as the definition in the OP, with the unique $p$ chosen to be $0$.

Comment: The problem with your definition it's that $\mathbb R^2$ would be a cone in $\mathbb R^3$, and so it's a little bit to general, no ?

Comment: @Holo exactly! And user330587, if you mean something like $(x,y,0)$ is a cone in $\mathbb{R}^3$ you are right and there is no problem with this.

Comment: So a set of half-lines that almost touch the origin are a cone? I didn't know that. My geometric intuition seems to fit only a convex cone.